# Google Play Console - The Android App Bundle was not signed

Tags: unity-game-engine, deployment, google-play-console, sha

I'm having a problem with uploading my game in the Google Play Console.

Platform I'm working on: Windows
Unity version: 2021.3.2f1
Also I'm using "App integrity" from Google Play Console.

The Error I get is: "The Android App Bundle was not signed."

The things I tried are:

- Keystore is setup correctly.
- I tried setting the Developer Build checked and unchecked. Neither of the options worked.
- SHA fingerprints are setup correctly.
- I have reset the SHA fingerprint values multiple times.